# Smoke test for iOS app

Tags: ios, smoke-testing

As we all know, there are unit test and UI test in Xcode. I'm confused about the smoke test and regression test. For now, I need to write smoke test and regression test for iOS app. How can I implement it? Does unit test contain the smoke test or is there another way to implement it? Thanks  in advance!

Comment: what *is* a smoke test for an iOS app? What would you expect the test to do?

Comment: To test the basic function of the app.

Comment: https://medium.com/@joesusnick/set-up-ios-smoke-tests-in-three-steps-1302bffb0417